# sql join parent record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables ClientVisit, Location and the join table ClientVisitLocation
the join table contains the history of the visits locations.

a basic join of the 3 tables could return a parent record or a child record.
location table has a column [parentGuid] if the record is the parent level then this = 0 otherwise it is the guid for the parent location.

to put it into context the locationID stored in the clientVisitLocation table could reference a Ward or a Bed. i want my query to return the Ward

i've joined the location table a second time but this gives me empty columns for l2 where l already contained the ward level. i want the ward level locations to appear in the same column.

```
Select cvl.*, l2.* from
cv3clientvisit cv
inner join CV3ClientVisitLocation cvl on cv.guid = cvl.clientvisitguid
inner join cv3Location l on CVl.locationguid = l.guid
left join cv3location l2 on l.locngrpguid = l2.guid
```

returns

```
-+
| visitid | Locn1ID |   Locn1Name   | Locn1parent | locn2ID | Locn2Name | Locn2Parent |  |
+---------+---------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------------+--+
|       1 |       1 | ward F - bed2 |        1234 | 1234    | WardF     | NULL        |  |
|       1 |       2 | ward F - bed4 |        1234 | 1234    | WardF     | NULL        |  |
|       1 |       3 | Ward B        |           0 | NULL    | NULL      | NULL        |  |
+---------+---------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------------+--+
```

i want it to return

```
+---------+---------+----------+
| visitid | Locn1ID | LocnName |
+---------+---------+----------+
|       1 |       1 | Ward F   |
|       1 |       2 | Ward F   |
|       1 |       3 | Ward B   |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

i could use a coalesce in the select part but as this is part of a join in a larger query that wouldnt give me the desired result.
i'm sure its fairly simple but i've got a mind block now.

Comment: Are you suing allscripts SunriseXA?  The Location table has a ragged hierarchy.  You might have to pull in a little bit more than what you have currently

Comment: i am indeed, the parentguid column i'm using is actually the LocnGrpGuid column but for people that dont know the DB its the same thing, the actualy parentguid could reference a bay. then i would have to join the location table a third time.

Comment: how do you distinguish between a ward and bed?  Is there a field with a value you want to target?

Comment: location has a column [typecode] that can = unit or bed. the bed will always have a parentguid to link it to the unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    A.visitid,
    A.Locn1ID,
    CASE 
      WHEN A.Locn2Name is null THEN A.Locn1Name 
      ELSE A.Locn2Name
    END 
    FROM (Select cvl.*, l2.* from
cv3clientvisit cv
inner join CV3ClientVisitLocation cvl on cv.guid = cvl.clientvisitguid
inner join cv3Location l on CVl.locationguid = l.guid
left join cv3location l2 on l.locngrpguid = l2.guid) as A
```

Comment: thats so obvious now! i was in the process of trying using CASE WHEN in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

A real quick note about Sunrise is that the hierarchy for locations is ragged.  A ward and a bed may have different distances in the tree, especially between two different campuses.  In addition some locations doesn't use Wards, some use units instead, some use clinics, etc...

This might be a bit overkill for what you need, I created a table function to find some additional information about location.  You can use the function below and join on the type code you are looking for.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[XXX_WhereAmI](@Location Numeric(16,0))
RETURNS @locationDetails Table(
GUID Numeric(16,0),
TypeCode Varchar(50),
Name Varchar(255),
ParentGUID Numeric(16,0),
FacilityGUID Numeric(16,0)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Facility as Numeric(16,0)
DECLARE @TypeCode as Varchar(30);
DECLARE @Facilities as TABLE(FacilityGUID Numeric(16,0))

INSERT INTO @Facilities
SELECT DISTINCT FacilityGUID
FROM [$(XAProd)]..CV3Location

SET @Facility = (SELECT FacilityGUID FROM [$(XAProd)]..CV3Location WHERE GUID = @Location)
--SELECT @FLocale
WHILE @Location NOT IN (SELECT FacilityGUID FROM @Facilities)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @locationDetails (GUID, TypeCode, Name, ParentGUID, FacilityGUID)
    SELECT  GUID,
            TypeCode,
            Name,
            ParentGUID,
            FacilityGUID
        FROM [$(XAProd)]..CV3Location WHERE GUID = @Location

    SET @Location = (SELECT ParentGUID FROM [$(XAProd)]..CV3Location WHERE GUID = @Location)
END


INSERT INTO @locationDetails (GUID, TypeCode, Name, ParentGUID, FacilityGUID)
SELECT  GUID,
    'Facility',
    Name,
    ParentGUID,
    FacilityGUID
FROM [$(XAProd)]..CV3Location WHERE GUID = @Facility

RETURN
END;
```

Comment: i think this is slight overkill for what i'm trying to do here, but will be v.useful for something else. so thanks.